# Get coursework from google classroom course

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, google-classroom

I'm trying to get a list of CourseWork objects from a list of courses and add each coursework object to a list. However I have no idea how to get the Coursework object, I'm thinking that it's to do with either eTags or Ids, but have no way of knowing. The code I'm using is below:

```
    public static IList<Course> GetAllCourses()
    {
        CoursesResource.ListRequest request = ClassService.Courses.List();
        request.PageSize = 100;

        ListCoursesResponse response = request.Execute();
        GoogleClassroomCourses = response.Courses;

        return GoogleClassroomCourses;
    }

    public static IList<CourseWork> GetCourseWork()
    {
        IList<string> courseIds = new List<string>();
        IList<string> eTags = new List<string>();

        foreach (Course course in GetAllCourses())
        {
            string id = course.Id;
            courseIds.Add(id);
            foreach (string cId in courseIds)
            {
                Course c = ClassService.Courses.Get(cId).Execute();
                eTags.Add(c.ETag);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Method: courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) using this HTTP request format:

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork
```

which, if successful, returns course work items that match the request in the response body.

Sample JSON representation:

```
{
  "courseWork": [
    {
      object(CourseWork)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
}
```